# VTK+PyQt5: Connecting slider values to translation variables

Tags: python, pyqt5, vtk

I used the code below and tried to change slider value with first variable of `transform.trasnlate(x,y,z)`
but I faced the error below:

TypeError: Translate argument %Id: %V

details: I want to change the position of STL file as the the slider moves up or down.

I think my problem is that I'm using a method instead of an integer number, but I don't know how to fix. it

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        #First STL file
        reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
        reader.SetFileName(filename)


        transform = vtk.vtkTransform()

        transform.Translate(self.size, 0, 0)


        transformFilter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
        transformFilter.SetTransform(transform)
        transformFilter.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        transformFilter.Update()

        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
            mapper.SetInput(transformFilter.GetOutput())
        else:
            mapper.SetInputConnection(transformFilter.GetOutputPort())

        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)


        self.vtkwidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.vtkwidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        

        #Slider
        self.title = "Rotaion"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        
        self.slider = QSlider()
        self.slider.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(10)
        self.slider.setMinimum(-100)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.handler)

        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.slider, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        
        # Create a rendering window and renderer
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkwidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        
        self.iren = self.vtkwidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)
        self.iren.Initialize()


        # Enable user interface interactor

        self.widget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()

    
    def handler(self):
        global size
            
        self.size = self.slider.value()
        print(self.size)
        #self.label.setText(str(self.size))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) is one of the basic default properties of *all* QWidget classes, and since all Qt properties are accessible as *callables* what you're getting with `self.size` (without parentheses) is a *reference to a method*, and that's clearly not an acceptable type for the transform. In any case, the `self.size()` will return a [QSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsize.html) value, which is also not an acceptable type.

So, two considerations must be done:

1. No existing attribute of the inherited class(es) should *ever* be overwritten for uses different from their scope; since you're using a QMainWindow, you'll need to ensure that you're not overwriting any of the properties or functions of QMainWindow, QWidget and QObject; I strongly recommend you to always check for them (you can see the full member list by clicking the *"List of all members, including inherited members"* link at the beginning of the documentation of each class), but the rule of thumb is: if it's a *very generic* attribute name (like "size", "width", "font") it probably exists already and should *not* be overwritten.
2. If `size` wasn't an already existing attribute, you'd have faced an `AttributeError`, because you never declared it before that point.

Finally, if you want to change the transform, you certainly cannot just do that by overwriting the `self.size` value; Python doesn't work like that, at least with simple instance attributes: you'll have only changed the value of `self.size`, but the transform object can know anything about that.

You need to connect the `valueChanged` signal to a slot that changes the transform (or sets a new one). I don't use Vtk, so the following is just some pseudo code:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

        self.transformSize = 0

        self.transform = vtk.vtkTransform()

        self.transform.Translate(self.transformSize, 0, 0)

        self.transformFilter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()

        # ...

    def handler(self, value):
        self.transformSize = value
        self.transform.Translate(value, 0, 0)
        self.transformFilter.Update()
```

Some considerations:

1. As with `size()`, you should also *not* overwrite other existing attributes like [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) or [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop).
2. Almost every signal that is emitted when some property has changed, provides the new value as argument, and that's also true for QAbstractSlider's `valueChanged`, so you don't need to use `self.slider.value()` inside `handler()` since that value is already the argument.
3. Grid layouts (as any other index-based object) are 0-index based, if you don't add anything to the first row or column of the grid (or you don't set a minimum height/width for them) there's no use adding widgets to the second row/column; also if the added widget is only using one "grid cell", the rowSpan and columnSpan arguments (the last `1, 1` in `addWidget`) are superfluous since they are the default values.
4. I don't know what that `global` in the `handler()` is doing there, since it's not used, but keep in mind that you should *always avoid globals*: the general rule is that "if you're using them, you're doing something wrong", or, better, "you should not use globals unless you know when you need them, and if you **really** know when you need them, you also know that you should not use them".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perfect suggestions.